# WPF - Can't align text in center of a button

Tags: wpf

I have the following custom button, which works perfectly:

**MyCustomButton**

```
<Button.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyCustomButton">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,10,20,10"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxHeight}" ClipToBounds="True">
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="4" BorderBrush="transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0088D9" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF007BC4" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="content" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto">
                                <Run x:Name="icon" Text="{Binding Path=Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                <Run x:Name="text" Text="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Button.Resources>
```

However, I can not do, no way, that the texts inside it (through the tags of "Run" named "Icon" and "Text") keep the centered alignment. What is the trick? Thanks in advance!

Comment: TextBlock.TextAlignment = Center ?

Comment: Have you tried to set the HorizantalAlignment=center to the grid?

Comment: I just tried this and still does not work! I'm going crazy!

Comment: Solved! I just removed all HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment and put TextAligment="Center" to TextBlock. Anyway, Thanks for the help!